# Let an element hover/float/prey on its place with jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, css-float

I would like to give an element the effect like it is slowly hovering/floating (or preying like a bird, if you like) fluidly on its place.
In other words, give it a little random movement, but keep it roughly on its place.

I tried to find this in a seach engine, but as you might imagine it gives a combination of jQuery and hover or float, a totally different result.

Does anyone have an idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery Floating Effect](http://www.inwebson.com/demo/jqfloat/)

I googled 'jQuery floating effect' -> and the first result is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a very interesting tool to use. You can actually see a wide range of *"effects"* that can give your page a more appealing look. I usually look into their site for interesting widgets and effects. Check out the link http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/ and you might be able to find something that may interest you!

Hope you have a great time! :)